# BitBucket + AppHarbor without NuGet

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, appharbor

I'm creating an OpenSource project on *BitBucket* (using *Mercurial*) (in *C#* with *Visual Studio 2010*, if it's important). The project has some external dependancies (*xUnit*, *StyleCop*, *Mono.Nat*, *BerkeleyDB*, ...). I want to use *AppHarbor* to make test builds and run tests.

- I don't want to use *NuGet* to download them (because some of them aren't in *NuGet* and so I would have to create a private *NuGet* repository, because the *StyleCop*/*MsBuild*/*NuGet* integration doesn't work very well. It requires two "rounds" of build to load correctly the *StyleCop.targets* file, but *AppHarbor* will only do one and finally because I think it's very bad to create an open source project that has an exe file inside that is automatically launched when the project is compiled. Would you launch a random exe contained in a solution you downloaded from Internet?).
- I don't want to include the external dependancies in the main tree (I'm very much against it).
- I want to have the external dependancies somewhere else (another *BitBucket* repository, for example).
- I don't have a server that can do a *cron* job and pull/push from one repository to another, but if you can find a *free* service that can do it for me it's ok as a solution.

How can I do it? I have tried adding multiple repositories to *AppHarbor*, but they are compiled one at a time (from an empty folder)

Comment: For #4 couldn't you have a single instance background worker on AppHarbor?

Comment: @Rangoric I had thought of it, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel unless it's very necessary. It would be at least two or three days of work to do it (I'm not even sure how I should do it... Should I pull locally the two repositories and then repush them on a third repository? Should I wait for the POST message of bitbucket and then trigger everything? But then I'm working on the WebWorker. What timeout is there for Webworkers to finish their work? So many questions... Just implementing the error handling would be a nightmare)